# C - Printing formatted output of money

Tags: c, formatting, printf, currency, right-justified

In my program I print out a table, one of the columns has money listed. I want to print out the money values neatly and **right justified**, like below:

```
  $9.00
  $8.00
 $19.20
$200.90
```

I can right justify the numbers like so

```
while(condition)
{
   printf("$%5.2f\n", number);
}
```

But obviously with this method the **$** isn't positioned where I want it, and I get an output more like:

```
$    9.00
$    8.00
$   19.20
$  200.90
```

Can I get the formatting I want simply with **printf**?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with auxiliary string:

```
while(condition)
{
   char str[10] = {};
   sprintf(str, "$%.2f", number);
   printf("%8s\n", str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is very difficult to achieve this by using simply `printf`. For currency-sensitive formatting you should use the [`strfmon()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strfmon.html) function.
For more detailed explanation read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19202869/2455888) given by [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler).