# How to align mutiple decimal percentage with printf

Tags: c

For percentage in form "x.%x", the first x <= 3 bits, the second x == 2 bits

```
a1 = 93.11;
a2 = 33.72;
a3 = 30.69;
b1 = 0.00;
b2 = 0.00;
b3 = 0.00;
printf("%3.2f%% %3.2f%% %3.2f%%\n", a1, a2, a3); // wrong, how to modify?
printf("%3.2f%% %3.2f%% %3.2f%%\n", b1, b2, b3);
```

Output:
93.11% 33.72% 30.69%
0.00% 0.00% 0.00%
But the output is not right. How to align to make output below:

[image]

Comment: you just want an extra leading on trailing zero no? I mean the issue is there is just one char worth of whitespace in there.

Comment: @Ashwin Gupta I've added an image.

Comment: I got you, but how do you intend to fill it? 0.00% has one less char then 93.11%, you need to fill it with something. Either whitespace, or a leading/trailing zero?

Comment: You did not read the documentation of the functions you use, did you?

Comment: Or look very hard to see if there was an existing question that provided the information you need. Possible duplicate of [Aligning printf() variables and decimals in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202242/aligning-printf-variables-and-decimals-in-c)

Comment: @Olaf I've read it before, but not very carefully. I'll read it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
printf("%5.2f%% %5.2f%% %5.2f%%\n", a1, a2, a3);
printf("%5.2f%% %5.2f%% %5.2f%%\n", b1, b2, b3);
```

The `5` means, print at least 5 characters.

```
12345
93.11  <== 5 total characters, counting the decimal point.
 0.00  <== 5 total characters, first char is a [space]
```

[Link to IDEOne Code](http://ideone.com/U5O5bg)

The output is:

```
93.11% 33.72% 30.69%
 0.00%  0.00%  0.00%
```